# Google Analytics Site Search: Showing "search" for site terms and not the actual keywords being searched

Tags: google-analytics

When I set up my search queries and categories in google analytics, the site term results I get are "search" and not the terms I type into the keyword search boxes. I can see the terms on the"destination pages" results, but I would like to see them pulled in the search terms to track the data correctly. Below is the search url and an image of my search page. As you can see, "category", "state", and "city" are category parameters, and I believe "keyword" is the search query. How should I set up the queries and categories in my settings? Any and all help is much appreciated!!

```
example.com/search-page/?category=&keyword%5B%5D=&keyword%5B%5D=&keyword%5B%5D=&keyword%5B%5D=&keyword%5B%5D=&state=&city=&submit=Search
```

[Search page snipit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzuWi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that at the submit of the form the `keyword` parameter was **one** with the various values ​​after its `=` symbol, in your case instead you have many fields that are called with the same name: `keyword`.

You can define up to 5 parameters, so you can change the name of each of your search fields (i.e.: keyword1, keyword2, ...) and set these in the View settings.

Comment: I appreciate your help! However, I don't understand. Are you saying I should rename the keyword slots so they have separate names/values?

Comment: Thank you! I'll try giving them different names to see if this works.

Comment: Great, let me know!